# Rails 4 produces "Migrations are pending"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are quite a few posts about this error of `Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`. `rails server` runs fine. However `localhost:3000` caused the error above. We applied all suggested solutions and none of thems seem work. The same error is keeping coming back after `development.sqlite3` were re-generated many times in our new `Rails 4.2` app.  We did:

1. Wipe out all migrate files and re-copy them over.
2. bundle exec db:create db:migrate

Here is the output of `bundle exec rake db:migrate:status`

```
database: C:/D/tj/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150528025117  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025118  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025119  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025120  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025121  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025122  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025123  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025124  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025125  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025126  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025127  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025128  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025129  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025130  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025131  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025132  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150528025133  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20150614235408  Create sys logs.authentify
  down    20150614235409  Create user levels.authentify
  down    20150614235410  Create users.authentify
  down    20150614235411  Create sys user groups.authentify
  down    20150614235412  Create sys modules.authentify
  down    20150614235413  Create sys module mappings.authentify
  down    20150614235414  Create authentify zones.authentify
  down    20150614235415  Create authentify group types.authentify
  down    20150614235416  Create authentify engine configs.authentify
  down    20150614235417  Create authentify user accesses.authentify
  down    20150614235418  Create authentify user roles.authentify
  down    20150614235419  Create authentify role definitions.authentify
  down    20150614235420  Create commonx misc definitions.commonx
  down    20150614235421  Create commonx logs.commonx
  down    20150614235422  Create commonx search stat configs.commonx
  down    20150614235423  Create state machine logx logs.state machine logx
  down    20150614235424  Create user manualx manuals.user manualx
  down    20150614235425  Create banquetx banquets.banquetx
  down    20150614235426  Create banquetx menus.banquetx
  down    20150614235427  Create banquet coursex courses.banquet coursex
```

We did not see the problem with the output of status. Here is the database.yml which is generated by `rails generator`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

What caused the migration pending error?

Comment: Myself faced the same error.What i did is deleted the records in the `schema_migrations` with the respective `VERSION` numbers whose migration status is `up` and later did `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: `@Pavan`, your comment remind us of schema_migrations table. Portion of the db was migrated from previous version of the db which has its own schema_migrations table. After schema_migrations table is deleted from the migration, then the error disappeared.  Obviously this table caused the pending error. Nice comment!